# connecting to a local database with nodejsn

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I want to have a database on my local hard-drive (say, made in MS Access) and connect to it with node.js (like you do with the MySql module).
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adodb

You will need to install MS Access Driver in your system (windows) to use it, but it applies to every other language too if you want to access MS Access db.